# System.Windows.Media.Color to color name

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0

I have the following:

```
Color color = Colors.Red;
color.ToString();
```

which outputs as the hexadecimal representation. Is there any way to output "Red"?

Bonus points to whoever gives a solutions that works with different cultures (i.e. output "Rojo" for spanish).

Comment: You need to set a bounty if you want to award bonus points.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you might have to hand-roll your own solution using Reflection. Here's my first shot:

```
public static string GetColorName(this System.Windows.Media.Color color)
{
    Type colors = typeof(System.Windows.Media.Colors);
    foreach(var prop in colors.GetProperties())
    {
        if(((System.Windows.Media.Color)prop.GetValue(null, null)) == color)
            return prop.Name;
    }

    throw new Exception("The provided Color is not named.");
}
```

Keep in mind that this is by no means efficient, but from what I can see in the documentation it would be the only way.

Comment: This is for Windows Phone 7 so I wonder if this code would pass certification

Comment: @Jonas Well, you could just run this code once and create a dictionary of known colors, and store it as a resource.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to convert the Media.Color to a Drawing.Color

```
private System.Drawing.Color ColorFromMediaColor(System.Windows.Media.Color clr)
{
  return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(clr.A, clr.R, clr.G, clr.B);
}
```

Then use the Name property from the Drawing.Color object to get the color name.

As for localizing, you could look up the [color name](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/Colors/default.aspx) in a translation dictionary built from resource files you provide.

Comment: This will certainly not work because color.name will not look up for every color you create.

Comment: The question asked for the color name for built-in color objects e.g. Color.Red, not arbitrary ones created by the user, so it should work.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work because System.Drawing is not part of the Silverlight CLR